# Learning Python- Defining get to return multiple values for keys in hashmap

Tags: python

In Learn Python the Hard Way, Lesson 39, you create a hashmap to import and use as a mimic of Python's built-in dictionary.

Initially, it is written so that the hashmap allows only one key at a time:

```
def get(aMap, key, default = None):
    """Gets the value in a bucket for the given key, or the default"""
    i, k, v = get_slot(aMap, key, default = default)
    return k, v

def set(aMap, key, value):
    """Sets the key to the value, replacing any existing values"""
    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)
    i, k, v = get_slot(aMap, key)

    if i >= 0:
    #the key exists, replace it
        bucket[i] = (key, value)
    else:
    #The key does not exist, append and create it
        bucket.append((key, value))
```

In the study drills, one if the challenges is to change it so that keys can have multiple values.  I did this by just having it append values, whether the key existed or not.

```
def set(myMap, key, value):
    bucket = get_bucket(myMap, key)
    i, k, v = get_slot(myMap, key)

    bucket.append((key, value))
```

If I run the following, it does in fact list everything I enter, without overwriting like the first set function would have:

```
jazz = myHashmap2.new()
myHashmap2.set(jazz, 'Miles Davis', 'Flamenco Sketches')
myHashmap2.set(jazz, 'Miles Davis', 'Kind of Blue')
myHashmap2.set(jazz, 'Duke Ellington', 'Beginning to see the light')
myHashmap2.set(jazz, 'Billy Strayhorn', 'Lush Life')

print "-----List Test-----"
myHashmap2.list(jazz)
```

I get:

```
-----List Test-----   
Billy Strayhorn Lush Life
Miles Davis Flamenco Sketches
Miles Davis Kind of Blue
Duke Ellington Beginning to see the light
```

However, I cannot seem to get the 'get' function to print both the 'Miles Davis' values.  It always reaches the value 'Flamenco Sketches' and leaves off the 'Kind of Blue'.

```
print "-----Get Test-----"
print ex39_hashmap.get(jazz, 'Miles Davis')
print ex39_hashmap.get(jazz, 'Duke Ellington')
print ex39_hashmap.get(jazz, 'Billy Strayhorn')

-----Get Test-----
('Miles Davis', 'Flamenco Sketches')
('Duke Ellington', 'Beginning to see the light')
('Billy Strayhorn', 'Lush Life')
```

I've tried several things:

```
def get(myMap, key, default = None):
    i, k, v = get_slot(myMap, key, default = default)

    if k == key:
        return (k, v)

def get(myMap, key, default = None):
    bucket = get_bucket(myMap, key)
    i, k, v = get_slot(myMap, key, default = default)
    for i, k in bucket:
        if k == key:
            return (k, v)
```

I assume it needs to be some kind of loop that runs through each key without just stopping when it sees it the first time, but I can't figure out what would do it.

Also, the loop I wrote just returns "None" for each get.  So I am clearly missing something (or several things).

What am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: You `return` the first time `k == key`, what did you expect would happen?

Comment: I'm not sure what I thought.  It makes sense that it would return the first k==key, but I figured if I did a loop, it would return _every_ instance where k==key.  Clearly, I am mistaken.

Comment: You need to figure out a way to move the `return` *outside* the `for` loop - once a function hits `return`, it's over.

Comment: Ah! I've been trying to figure this out all day! I can get it to print the right answers, but it also prints None for each key that doesn't match. Any resource you can point me to to figure it out?

Comment: Please don't tell me the answer, just a resource that could help me figure it out. I need to learn this without being told completely, if that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

But this behavior: Having a unique key-value pair, is actually what you want! If you have 2 keys that are the same, a hash function can't work, right!?.

In you case, this behavior is achieved by your line:

```
#the key exists, replace it
bucket[i] = (key, value)
```

This is also how the Python dictionaries work. Here is an example:

```
my_dict1 = dict()
my_dict1['Miles Davis'] = 'Flamenco Sketches'
my_dict1['Miles Davis'] = 'Kind of Blue'
my_dict1['Duke Ellington'] = 'Beginning to see the light'

print(my_dict1)
{'Duke Ellington': 'Beginning to see the light', 'Miles Davis': 'Kind of Blue'}
```

You can have a workaround where you make the value a mutable object and append to it if you want to have multiple "values" associated with one key:

```
my_dict2 = dict()
my_dict2['Miles Davis'] = ['Flamenco Sketches']
my_dict2['Miles Davis'].append('Kind of Blue')
my_dict2['Duke Ellington'] = 'Beginning to see the light'

print(my_dict2)

{'Duke Ellington': 'Beginning to see the light', 'Miles Davis': ['Flamenco Sketches', 'Kind of Blue']}
```

Comment: So, how could I include that key.append in the set Def?

Comment: I tried several things in the if I >= 0: statement, but couldn't get it to append

Comment: There is no need to create an append function, that's not the idea of an hash table but a completely different concept. If you want to mimic the python dict, just use a key,value pair like before but use a python list object as value. Then, if you return the value via your set function, just use the append method for lists.